# Рекурсивное создание полей теста

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Я пытаюсь динамически создать тест по кнопке. Добавил функцию

```js
function addTestBlock(parent){
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";
  input.size = "80";
  input.style.marginTop = "20px";
  
  var delete_input = document.createElement('button');
  delete_input.innerHTML = "Удалить";
  delete_input.onclick = function(){
   $('#'+parent.id).remove();
  };

  parent.appendChild(input);
  parent.appendChild(delete_input);
 }
```

Которая добавляет в нужном мне месте строку ввода ответа и кнопку "удалить", которая будет удалять эту строку и саму кнопку.

Затем в нужном блоке я вызываю эту функцию, которая добавляет в него div со строкой и кнопкой, и туда же кнопку "добавить". Вешаю на нее ту же самую функцию. В итоге действие кнопки "добавить" не изменяется - она ищет index.html. Все остальное работает.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var parent = document.createElement('div'); 
parent.id = 'option'+count_options;
addInputBlock(parent);

question_div.appendChild(parent);

var add_input = document.createElement('button');
add_input.innerHTML = "Добавить";
add_input.onclick = function() {
  addInputBlock(parent);
};

container.appendChild(question_div);
container.appendChild(add_input);
```

П.С. попробовал разные варианты присвоения на onclick, не могу понять в чем проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var delete_input = document.createElement('button');
delete_input.type = "button";
...

var add_input = document.createElement('button');
add_input.type = "button";
...
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! часа два мучился...

Comment: @ДмитрийСоловьев Пожалуйста. Вам понятно, почему это помогло?

Comment: получается что при создании атрибут type инициализируется как "submit", и ищет мой index.html, которого нету